# set() in ArrayList

Tags: java, arraylist

I am new to Java, please help me.

My program is

```
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;
class Test
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        ArrayList al=new ArrayList();
        al.add("a");
        al.add("b");
        for(int i=1;i<=10;i++)
        {
            al.add(i);
        }
        al.remove("a");
        al.set(1,"c");
        for(int j=3;j<=al.size();j++)
        {
            al.set(j,"z");
        }

        System.out.println(al);
    }
};
```

in above any mistake........plz help me

Comment: What is the nature of the problem? Compilation or runtime? What are you expecting the code to do?

Comment: It is generally advisable to post the error messages you get if you want any advise here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

a) You need to make the class public to run it:

```
public class Test
{
```

<s>b) the last semi-colon is a syntax error</s> No it's not, it's just unnecessary noise.

c) This fails with an `IndexOutOfBoundsException`:

```
for(int j = 3; j <= al.size(); j++){
    al.set(j, "z");
}
```

It needs to be:

```
for(int j = 3; j < al.size(); j++){
    al.set(j, "z");
}
```

**Explanation:** List Indexes are zero-based, so the highest position in a List with n elements is n-1

---

BTW, the above code can be written in a more elegant way like this:

```
Collections.fill(al.subList(3, al.size()), "z");
```

Reference:

- [`Collections.fill(List<T>, T)`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#fill%28java.util.List,%20T%29)
- [`List.subList(from, to)`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/List.html#subList%28int,%20int%29)

Comment: The semi-colon should be OK there.

Comment: I know, I'd already changed that. It serves no purpose and it's confusing, but it won't do any harm

Answer (score 1):

This code will throw an IndexOutOfBounds exception because of the line:

```
    for (int j = 3; j <= al.size(); j++) {
```

to fix it, you need to change it to:

```
    for (int j = 3; j < al.size(); j++) {
```

This is because the <= means that your for loop iterates over the end of the list.

Answer (score 0):

List~ and Arrayindices start at 0, not 1. So if you have a list of 3 Elements, they go from index: 0, 1, 2. So you normally iterate from (i = 0; i < list.size (); ++i). Less than, not less/equal.

```
for (int j=3; j < al.size (); j++)
```

Answer (score 0):

1.The semicolon in the last line

2.change the code from

```
for(int j=3;j<=al.size();j++)
```

to

```
for(int j=3;j<al.size();j++)
```

Arraylist are always accessed from from 0th index to less than the size of the array.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is necessary to change also the start index from 3 to 2:

```
for (int j=2; j < al.size (); j++)
```